# cast of a structure into another one to get specific data

Tags: c, casting, struct

I have this structure representing a generic message

```
typedef struct {
    uint16_t length;    
    uint8_t type1;      
    uint8_t type2;      
    uint8_t *data;      
} generic_msg_t;
```

After reading type1 and type 2 I can know to which specific message it corresponds, for example this one:

```
 typedef struct {
     uint16_t length;   
     uint8_t type1;     
     uint8_t type2;     
     uint16_t a;
     uint8_t b;
     uint8_t c;
     double d;
     double e;
     double f;
     double g;
     double h;
     uint8_t i;
 } specific_msg_t;
```

Supposing msg contains verified data, I would like to understand why if I do this I can not access to d, e, f, g, h data (but well a, b, c)

```
specific_msg_t * specific_msg = (specific_msg_t *) msg;
uint16_t a = specific_msg->a; //OK
double d = specific_msg->d; //NOK`
```

I have to do instead:

```
unsigned char * buffer = (unsigned char *) msg;
double d = buffer[15] + (buffer[14] << 8) + (buffer[13] << 16) + (buffer[12] << 24) + (buffer[11] << 32) + (buffer[10] << 40) + (buffer[9] << 48) + (buffer[8] << 56);`
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Are the messages arriving over the network?  If they are, do you know whether sender and receiver agree on what padding will be applied to `specific_msg_t`?

Comment: Clearly this is a failure to communicate.  Pick up the phone, call the other guy and ask him why he's sending a `long long` instead of a double.  We can't help you find him.

Comment: `(buffer[8] << 56)` is not unlikely to invoke undefined behaviour. You should cast to `uint64_t` before shifting, probably.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Your generic message has a generic pointer to "something" called data. Why? Is it possible that this is actually a pointer to the specific message data?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the sender and receiver use the same headers (uint16_t is the same for both of them) and both of them use the same architecture (e.g. x86 or whatever) there shouldn't be too many problems.
I would also define a union with all the specific message types that you need, in order to avoid those nasty calculations and most of the casts.
Something similar to this:

```
typedef struct {
    uint16_t length;    
    uint8_t type1;      
    uint8_t type2;   

    // whatever you need here...
    double a;
    float b;
    // etc.
} specific_msg_t1;

 typedef struct {
     uint16_t length;   
     uint8_t type1;     
     uint8_t type2;     
     uint16_t a;
     uint8_t b;
     uint8_t c;
     double d;
     double e;
     double f;
     double g;
     double h;
     uint8_t i;
 } specific_msg_t2;

 typedef struct
 {
    uint16_t length;    
    uint8_t type1;     
    uint8_t type2;     
 } selector_msg_t;

 typedef union
 {
    selector_msg_t  selector;
    specific_msg_t1 msgtype1;
    specific_msg_t2 msgtype2;
 } message_type_t;
```

With this setup you could be sending messages of type "message_type_t". Use the member "selector" to decide which specific type of message you received and then use the appropriate specific type to read the different data members.
If the size difference is considerable between the specific types, then it is a bad idea, but if you're not limited by bandwidth then it's at least readable and not that error prone.

Answer (score 0):

`specific_msg_t` has potentially different alignment requirements than `generic_msg_t` so on some architectures, that code could result in a crash - the compiler has no particular requirement to align a generic_msg_t object on a boundary suitable for accessing a double.

It would help to know exactly what error you're getting though.